# Ошибки компиляции для мода

Tags: java, minecraft

Нужно было в одном .class файле изменить вебхук для дискорда, но после изменения этот .class файл просто не компилировался! Потом попробовал этот файл компилировать без изменений - и тут ошибки.

> **C:\Windows\system32> javac C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:3: error: package
> chylex.bettersprinting.client does not exist import
> chylex.bettersprinting.client.ClientOperations;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:4: error: package
> chylex.bettersprinting.system does not exist import
> chylex.bettersprinting.system.Log;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:10: error: package
> net.minecraft.client does not exist import
> net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:11: error: package
> net.minecraft.util does not exist import net.minecraft.util.Session;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:12: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:13: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:14: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:15: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:16: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:17: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLServerStartingEvent;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:18: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkCheckHandler;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:19: error: package
> net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher does not exist import
> net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
> ^ C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:21: error: cannot
> find symbol @Mod(modid = "bettersprinting", version = "2.3.0", name =
> "Better Sprinting", useMetadata = true, guiFactory =
> "chylex.bettersprinting.client.gui.ModGuiFactory",
> acceptableRemoteVersions = "*", updateJSON =
> "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chylex/Better-Sprinting/master/UpdateInfo.json",
> acceptedMinecraftVersions = "[1.8.9]")  ^   symbol: class Mod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:24: error: cannot
> find symbol   public static BetterSprintingProxy proxy;
> ^   symbol:   class BetterSprintingProxy   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:26: error: cannot
> find symbol   public static BetterSprintingConfig config;
> ^   symbol:   class BetterSprintingConfig   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:34: error: cannot
> find symbol   Session session =
> Minecraft.func_71410_x().func_110432_I();   ^   symbol:   class
> Session   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:53: error: cannot
> find symbol   public void onPreInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent e) {
> ^   symbol:   class FMLPreInitializationEvent   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:60: error: cannot
> find symbol   public void onInit(FMLInitializationEvent e) {
> ^   symbol:   class FMLInitializationEvent   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:65: error: cannot
> find symbol   public void posttInit(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
> ^   symbol:   class FMLInitializationEvent   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:87: error: cannot
> find symbol   public void onServerStarting(FMLServerStartingEvent e) {
> ^   symbol:   class FMLServerStartingEvent   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:92: error: cannot
> find symbol   public boolean onNetworkCheck(Map<String, String>
> versions, Side side) {
> ^   symbol:   class Side   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:23: error: cannot
> find symbol   @SidedProxy(clientSide =
> "chylex.bettersprinting.client.ClientProxy", serverSide =
> "chylex.bettersprinting.server.ServerProxy")    ^   symbol:   class
> SidedProxy   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:52: error: cannot
> find symbol   @EventHandler    ^   symbol:   class EventHandler
>
> location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:59: error: cannot
> find symbol   @EventHandler    ^   symbol:   class EventHandler
>
> location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:64: error: cannot
> find symbol   @EventHandler    ^   symbol:   class EventHandler
>
> location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:86: error: cannot
> find symbol   @EventHandler    ^   symbol:   class EventHandler
>
> location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:91: error: cannot
> find symbol   @NetworkCheckHandler    ^   symbol:   class
> NetworkCheckHandler   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:34: error: cannot
> find symbol   Session session =
> Minecraft.func_71410_x().func_110432_I();
> ^   symbol:   variable Minecraft   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:54: error: cannot
> find symbol
> Log.load();
> ^   symbol:   variable Log   location: class BetterSprintingMod C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:55: error: cannot
> find symbol
> config = new BetterSprintingConfig(e.getSuggestedConfigurationFile());
> ^   symbol:   class BetterSprintingConfig   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:68: error: cannot
> find symbol
> ClientOperations webhook = new ClientOperations(wh);
> ^   symbol:   class ClientOperations   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:68: error: cannot
> find symbol
> ClientOperations webhook = new ClientOperations(wh);
> ^   symbol:   class ClientOperations   location: class BetterSprintingMod
> C:\Users\vasok\Documents\BetterSprintingMod.java:69: error: package
> ClientOperations does not exist
> webhook.addEmbed((new ClientOperations.EmbedObject())
> ^ 33 errors**

Answer (score 0):

для компиляции надо скачивать среду разработки чтобы было видно все ошибки, и ещё среду разработки под майнкрафт forge src на gradle так как использует библиотеки при сборке, просто через javac мод не собрать, если получиться то он не запуститься все равно